# How to override the .get() method in requests?

Tags: python, overriding, python-requests

I would like the `.get()` method in `requests` to do extra operations beside the `GET` itself:

- print out "hello world" (in reality this will be logging)
- wait 5 seconds before issuing the actual `GET` (in reality this will be a more complex wait-and-retry operation)

Right now my simplistic solution is to use a function which actually calls `requests.get()`:

```
def multiple_requests(self, url, retries=5, wait=5):
        """
        retries several times an URL
        :param
        url: the url to check
        retries: how meny times to retry
        wait: number of seconds to wait between retries
        :return: the requests response, or None if failed
        """
        for _ in range(retries):
            try:
                r = requests.get(url)
            except Exception as e:
                self.log.error("cannot connect to {url}: {e}, retrying in {wait} seconds".format(url=url, e=e, wait=wait))
            else:
                if r.ok:
                    return r
                else:
                    self.log.error(
                        "error connecting to {url}, code {e}, retrying in {wait} seconds".format(
                            url=url, e=r.status_code, wait=wait
                        )
                    )
            finally:
                time.sleep(wait)
        # give up after several tries
        self.log.error("cannot connect to {url} despite retries, giving up".format(url=url))
        return None
```

but I have a strong feeling that it would be possible to override the actual `.get()` method in requests.

I use object programming in a very basic way and that would be an opportunity to actually learn the override part. There are [various](http://blog.devzero.com/2013/01/28/how-to-override-a-class-method-in-python/) [tutorials](http://lgiordani.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/) on how to override and call the parent class methods (which is exactly what I want to do: be able to finally use the original `.get()` method)

I therefore tried a basic override:

```
import requests

class MyRequest(requests.Request):
    def get(self, url, **kwargs):
        print("hello world")
        # calling the parent .get() method to actually GET something
        super(MyRequest, self).get(url, **kwargs)

r = MyRequest.get('http://google.com')
```

This code fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yop/dev/infoscreen/testingrequestsclass.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = MyRequest.get('http://google.com')
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

To be honest, I am stuck here. The tutorials all start with a definition of the parent class, while what I have is hidden (there is [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`requests.get` is just a function](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L57-L65), you can override it. It is *not* a method on the `requests.Requests` model:

```
import requests.api

def my_get(url, **kwargs):
    print('Hello World!')
    kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
    return requests.api.request('get', url, **kwargs)

requests.api.get = my_get
```

This then uses a *new session object* to handle the request.

Instead of replacing `requests.get()`, I'd provide a subclass of the `requests.Session()` object, overriding the [`Session.request()` method](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L382-L463), then use an instance of that session object:

```
from requests import Session

class MySession(Session):
    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        print('Hello World!')
        return super().request(method, url, **kwargs)
```

then use that like this:

```
with MySession() as session:
    response = session.get(url)
```

The advantage here is that you then can also make use of the full feature set that session objects offer, plus your additional code will also work for POST and PUT and DELETE and HEAD, etc. requests.

Comment: This is a very clear answer, thank you. I will use the second approach which is indeed more complete. I get, however, a `AttributeError: 'MySession' object has no attribute 'decode'` error when running it (on google.com), as a resutlt to a call `out = string.decode(encoding)` at ` File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 690, in to_native_string`.

Comment: @WoJ: sorry, my mistake; I passed in `self` as the first argument to the `super()` call. Removed now.

Comment: Thank you. As a side note if someone gets there, the `super()` call for Python 2 will be `super(MySession, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)`

Comment: @WoJ: right, I assumed you were using Python 3 because you were using `print()` as a function.

Comment: true, I use `print()` as a function (and systematically `.format()` with named arguments) as I find this more natural (probably one of the reasons for the change in Python 3)